# Login Success but after login success error session denied

Tags: php, mysql

please help my login is successfully done but after login logout automatically I am beginner please help me. please check attached images.

[Access Denied Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Oi8X.jpg)

[Login success image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtVyy.jpg)

login.php

```
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
if (empty($email)) {
            array_push($errors, "Email is required");
        }
        if (empty($password)) {
            array_push($errors, "Password is required");
        }
if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $Hpassword = hash('sha512', $_POST['password']);
            $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email' AND password='$Hpassword'";
            $mysqli_query = mysqli_query($con, $query);
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['id'] = session_id();
    $_SESSION['login_type'] = "user";
            echo '<script>alert("Login Success.");window.location.assign("home.php");</script>';
        }
    }
```

Checklogin.php

```
 <?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && $_SESSION['login_type']=='user'){
}
else{
    echo '<script>alert("Access denied");window.location.assign("index.php");</script>';
}
?>
```

Comment: you have to start session on login page. then only your session parameters will save & accessible on next page

Answer (score 0):

You are missing session_start() in login.php page

```
session_start();
    if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
            $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
    if (empty($email)) {
                array_push($errors, "Email is required");
            }
            if (empty($password)) {
                array_push($errors, "Password is required");
            }
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
            $Hpassword = hash('sha512', $_POST['password']);
                $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email' AND password='$Hpassword'";
                $mysqli_query = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                $_SESSION['userid'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['id'] = session_id();
        $_SESSION['login_type'] = "user";
                echo '<script>alert("Login Success.");window.location.assign("home.php");</script>';
            }
        }
```